# populate UITableView form array recived from JSON with sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an array that receive it in a JSON query, sort the array need a table of sections in alphabetical order .

I managed to sort the array alphabetically but I can not split this array into sections.

I found an example with NSDicctionary but i don`t know how to fill it . Thanks in advance!

```
   animals = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
            @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
            @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
            @"E" : @[@"Emu"],
            @"G" : @[@"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea"],
            @"H" : @[@"Hippopotamus", @"Horse"],
            @"K" : @[@"Koala"],
            @"L" : @[@"Lion", @"Llama"],
            @"M" : @[@"Manatus", @"Meerkat"],
            @"P" : @[@"Panda", @"Peacock", @"Pig", @"Platypus", @"Polar Bear"],
            @"R" : @[@"Rhinoceros"],
            @"S" : @[@"Seagull"],
            @"T" : @[@"Tasmania Devil"],
            @"W" : @[@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"]};
```

Comment: what do you want to do with this dictionary?

Comment: sorry rmaddy, I want to know why "iphone" and "xcode" tags are poorly related to this question in your opinion

Comment: the question in particular about tableview and nsdictionary. your question doesnt deal the issue with iphone /xcode. Hence poorly related!!!!

Comment: ok, I only wanted to know who was doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the array you got back

```
NSArray* animals = @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo",@"Camel", @"Cockatoo",@"Dog", @"Donkey",@"Emu",@"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea",@"Hippopotamus", @"Horse",@"Koala",@"Lion", @"Llama",@"Manatus", @"Meerkat",@"Panda", @"Peacock", @"Pig", @"Platypus", @"Polar Bear",@"Rhinoceros",@"Seagull",@"Tasmania Devil",@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"];
```

You can do something like this to get that dictionary

```
NSArray* alphabets = @[@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z"];
NSMutableDictionary* indexedAnimals = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString* letter in alphabets)
{
    NSArray* filteredAnimals = [animals filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString* evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
    {
        return [evaluatedObject hasPrefix:letter];
    }]];
    if ([filteredAnimals count])
    {
        indexedAnimals[letter] = filteredAnimals;
    }
}
NSArray* sectionLetters = [[indexedAnimals allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Then configure your table view

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [sectionLetters count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return sectionLetters[section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [indexedAnimals[sectionLetters[section]] count]
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *animal = indexedAnimals[sectionLetters[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = animal;

    return cell;
}
```